# Convert any base to binary

Tags: binary, radix

Is there a algorithm or formula that can convert any base n, say 2 to 36, to binary? I've looked around the web and can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to get you started.

```
unsigned strtou(const char *s, unsigned base) {
  unsigned y = 0;
  while (*s) {
     unsigned digit;
     if (isdigit(*s)) digit = ch - '0';
     else if (isupper(*s)) digit = ch - 'A' + 10;
     else if (islower(*s)) digit = ch - 'a' + 10;
     else Handle_IllegalDigit();
     if (digit >= base) Handle_IllegalDigit();

     y = y*base + digit;
     s++;
  }
  return y;
}
```